# How to check if specific class is inside list and return index?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have list of objects. These objects are sharing same abstract class. Is there any way how to get indexOf specific object based on class name?

Something like this:

```
open fun getScreenIndex(screen: Class<out FlowScreen>): Int{
     return flowList.indexOf(screen)
}
```

And I would call it like this:

```
getScreenIndex(AccountScreen::class.java)
```

Im building dynamic `ViewPager` which will be populated by screens and I need a way how to switch pages, but I don't wanna use indices (random numbers inside code - its confusing). Its way better to just call screen name. There wont be a case, when you will have same class twice in that list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```kotlin
val index = flowList.indexOfFirst { item -> item::class.java == AccountScreen::class.java }
```

You could also  change `Class<out FlowScreen>` to `Class<*>`